# Application structure meteor 1.4

Tags: meteor

I've installed `meteor-useraccounts/core`. In the documentation it says to use `lib/config/at_config.js` . Where does it go using the new recommend meteor file structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put it in to `/imports/startup/`  and import it in `/imports/startup/server/index.js`.

For details of file structure in Meteor read [Meteor Application Structure](https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#javascript-structure). Particularly [this portion](https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#javascript-structure).

Comment: Thanks. I've read the documents you suggested. I've never used imports etc before and I'm finding it a little confusing. Thanks for your help.